# Oracle timestamp issue to convert date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, etl

I am stuck in a data warehousing task where I need to map a column sourced as **varchar2** datatype, and a target in **TIMESTAMP (6)  WITH TIME ZONE** datatype.

Data format contained in source: `2019-08-20`

I tried using this mapping:

```
select to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-08-20',  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mi:sstzhtzm'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM tzh:tzm')  from dual;
```

which actually works for `dual` table.

But when the data loads in target this is the output given:

```
12/1/9999 12:00:00.000000 AM +00:00
```

Desired and expected output:

```
2019-08-20 12:00:00 AM +02:00
```

Comment: I'm confused.  If you only have a date format, why are you including the time component in the format?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have to load the data in a specific table which has a column declared in that TIMESTAMP 6 WITH TIME ZONE datatype

Comment: Are you claiming that a string value in your source table of `'2019-08-20'` is converted to a timestamp datatype of `12/1/9999 12:00:00.000000 AM +00:00`??? Hmmm, sounds unlikely. In fact that looks suspiciously like a **magic value** somebody might use to avoid having a null as an END_DATE.

Comment: @APC basically when data loads in a column declared TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE I get that output 12/1/9999 12:00:00.000000 AM +00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have only precision till date available with you in the `varchar2`, all other part of the `timestamp` (hour, minute, second and fraction of second) will be 0.
Try this:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-08-20',  'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=82aa18bb6d39c8063840205e539d9db5)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, apparently I was overlooking the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do TO_CHAR if you're inserting into a TIMESTAMP column?

Just insert this:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-08-20',  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mi:sstzhtzm') from dual;
```